# Magento Ajax Cart not working properly

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm having a problem with magento ajax cart. When I add or remove a product in the cart, the product is added and also excluded. However it does not appear when I add and does not add when I delete and only with reload of the page. There is no error in console,log and everything is okay.

It returns successfully message but it does not display the product in the cart, nor does it exclude when it is the case, only when I reload the page

link-> 
[www.maressamoda.com.br](http://www.maressamoda.com.br)

When remove.

```
{message: "Item was removed.", r: "success"}
message
:
"Item was removed."
r
:
"success"
```

When I add

```
{product_name: "Camiseta Fitness Don't Stop At Good Ref: 10094",…}
message
:
"Camiseta Fitness Don't Stop At Good Ref: 10094 was added into cart."
product_name
:
"Camiseta Fitness Don't Stop At Good Ref: 10094"
r
:
"success"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ajax Cart Configuration try configure a custom **XML of update blocks**.

Look like this

[image: XML of update blocks]

Comment: @Oxigênio That was exactly the problem, thanks for the help, I made the xml settings and it worked. Tenks!!!!

Comment: @MichaelCosta if tihis solved you problem, please upvote and accept this answer to close this :)